# template-type-related compile time error occur where theoretically not

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I have a template function `template<class T> T exc(T())` where T can sometime be void.

This function is used to execute a function and return the value (if it's not void).

This is the simplified content of `exc` (of course I have other content =p)

```
template<class T> T exc(T (*func)()){
    if(strcmp(typeid(T).name(), "void")){
        T obj = (*func)();
        // there are something to do with obj
        return obj;
    } else{
        (*func)();
    }
}

// in main:
exc<void>([]() -> void{std::cout << "I'm too lazy to type another function"
        << " so I use lambda" << std::endl;});
```

As you may know, `strcmp` return `0` when `typeid(T).name()` equals to `"void"`.

That is, there are no problem with runtime theoretically. However, this is the error

```
error C2182 : illegal use of type 'void'
```

I use MSVC cl command line compiler, and I think the problem may be caused by the compiler which substitute each template type from where function is invoked for T, so at `T obj`, the error occur.

I want to ask that is there any alternate solution for this? Is there any other way to declare obj so that the compiler treat it as 'correct'? Or should I override exc with `void exc(void (*func)())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading is the answer if your "actual code" does something more involved with the templated type

```
template<class T> T exc(T (*func)()){
        T obj = (*func)();
        // there's something to do with obj
        return obj;
}

void exc(void (*func)()){
        // something to do with void?
        (*func)();
}
```

(anyway you will not be able to explicitly state the template parameter in the `void` case, a specialization could do it but pay attention [to some overloading vs specialization resolutions](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)).

Finally you could as well return a `void` call

```
void fun() {}

template <class T>
T exc(T (*func)()) {
    return func();
}

exc<void>(fun);
```

One thing to keep in mind is that when compiling templated code, **all the in-scope branches should be valid at any time**. An if branch is NOT going to be "dead-code eliminated" magically if the templated type doesn't match - it will yield an error.

Answer (score 2):

Just do :

```
template <class T>
T exc(T (*func)()) {
    return func();
}
```

You can `return` an expression of `void` type from a void function.

**Edit:** if you need to apply a special treatment to `obj`, [don't specialize your function template](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). Overload it :

```
void exc(void (*func)()) {
    func();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error because the two branches has to be valid and

```
if(strcmp(typeid(T).name(), "void")){
    T obj = (*func)();
    // there are something to do with obj
    return obj;
}
```

is not valid for `T == void` (even if the branch would not be taken)

You may use overload to solve your problem:

```
template<class T> T exc(T (*func)()){
    T obj = (*func)();
    // there are something to do with obj
    return obj;
}

void exc(void (*func)()){
    (*func)();
}
```